# What is the formula for Nichrome

Tags: temperature, heat

Having no knowledge of electricals, I am interested in learning the applications of Nichrome.

I understand it has swg ratings. But what I am looking for is a formula that can calculate a particular thing if other certain inputs are provided.

Like the V = I/R triangle, is there a formula for Nichrome containing the following propreties:

Voltage, Amperage, Temperature of Nichrome, Length of Nichrome wire and Rating of Nichrome wire (swg) - I believe these are all the variables applicable, please correct me if I am wrong.

Example 1: 
So for instance, if I input the Temperature of the Nichrome I want to achieve, say 50C celius, the length of the Nichrome wire to be 2 Inches and the 32 swg rating, using these, can the formula calculate the voltage and amperage requirements?

Example 2:
Using the inputs, voltage, amperage, length of wire and swg rating, can it calculate the temperature?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome

Comment: Thanks @JImDearden. I did read that but I needed a more subjective answer to my question hence the post (sorry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nichrome wire is essentially a resistor. It varies its resistance slightly over temperature, but the basic idea is it's just a resistor dissipating power. It's nothing magical, just conservation of energy. A vast majority of the electrical energy being dissipated by the nichrome wire will be as heat.

[This site](http://www.wiretron.com/nicrdat.html) gives a tabulated chart for relating size of the nichrome, temperature, and amperage required.

Comment: Thank you. Does Voltage not play a part in the chart?

Comment: @KickAss It certainly plays a part, but is not listed, current is usually the limiting factor for power supplies. Relate the sizes on the amperage chart with the resistance chart, use Ohm's law to find the approximate voltage to get the listed current.

Comment: @kickass keep in mind this tables have reference of 110V. In case that you have no knowledge of basic electricals in theory and practice, I suggest to refrain from circuits that involves heat and high voltage

Comment: @GRTech Thank you, I was thinking of more like 6v and 0.5amps power source, would Nichrome of about 2 inches reach 50 degrees celcius?

Comment: The temperature reached by any heating element depends considerably on its environment.  If it is in a closed insulated box, it will get much hotter than if it is in the open, with a fan blowing air past it.

Comment: @PeterBennett Since he deside a final temperature, means that he makes a basic thermal calculation.

Comment: Thanks guys, I shall experiement with some very small amounts of power and safety equipment to obtain my desired results. All your input is appreciated.

Comment: I think you have an application that you can implement using ordinary resistors connected in a mix serial/parallel topology. Why you are insist in nichrome?

Comment: I thought resistors did not get as hot as Nichrome. I read that Nichrome is used specifically as a heating element and due to its design and its flexible properties, I can get it in the size and shape I need it to be. Resistors are limited in shape and size.

Comment: @KickAss Many power resistors can safely reach temperatures around 200°C. They can unsafely get much hotter. Nichrome is useful for much hotter temperatures without burning up. Your size and shape arguments are ok, both are limited in the form factors available.